# How to append data to nested array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am trying to **add data** to **nested arra**y and already tried out many **stackoverflow** **links** to solve out this problem but failed to do so.

**Original Data:**

```
cuisine: [
                    [
                        "Middle Eastern",
                        4
                    ],
                    [
                        "Western",
                        4
                    ],
                    [
                        "Pasta Dishes",
                        2
                    ],
                    [
                        "Salad",
                        2
                    ],
                    [
                        "Mexican",
                        1
                    ],
                    [
                        "Soup",
                        1
                    ],
                    [
                        "snacks",
                        1
                    ]
                ],
```

**Desired Data:**

```
cuisine: [
                    [
                        1
                        false
                        "Middle Eastern",
                        4
                    ],
                    [
                        2
                        false
                        "Western",
                        4
                    ],
                    [
                        3
                        false
                        "Pasta Dishes",
                        2
                    ],
                    [
                        "Salad",
                        2
                    ],
                    [
                        4
                        false
                        "Mexican",
                        1
                    ],
                    [
                        5
                        false
                        "Soup",
                        1
                    ],
                    [
                        6
                        false
                        "snacks",
                        1
                    ]
                ],
```

**My code**

```
  this.setState({ cousineArray: cuisine }, () => {
    this.addValuesToArray(this.state.cousineArray);
  });


  addValuesToArray = commingArray => {
    console.warn(commingArray);
    if (commingArray !== null && commingArray !== undefined) {
      for (i = 0; i < commingArray.length; i++) {
        this.setState(
          {
            commingArray: this.state.commingArray.push(i, false)
          },
          () => {
            console.log("Coming Array ==> ", commingArray[1]);
          }
        );
      }
    }
```

};

but its not working and throwing following error

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

What thing I am doing wrong. please tell me the better way if this is not well way to do this. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you should use an array of a particular type rather than an unstructured 2D array.  Unless you're limited to working with that structure by a 3rd party!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `forEach` loop to push values in the array using your own logic

```js
var cuisine= [
  [
    "Middle Eastern",
    4
  ],
  [
    "Western",
    4
  ],
  [
    "Pasta Dishes",
    2
  ],
  [
    "Salad",
    2
  ],
  [
    "Mexican",
    1
  ],
  [
    "Soup",
    1
  ],
  [
    "snacks",
    1
  ]
]
cuisine.forEach(function(e,j){
e.unshift(false)
e.unshift(j)
e.unshift({key:'value'})
})
console.log(cuisine)
```

Comment: can we also add key to the newly added values like e.push("checked",false) and e.push("id",j)?

Comment: Keys value pairs can be added to objects which support it. Array do not support key value pairings

Comment: However you can add objects in the array. Check edits

Comment: How to achieve this?

Comment: Can we add newly added values at the start instead of at the end?

Answer (score 2):

Do not set state in a loop, also use `map` to properly set values to your nested array:

```
addValuesToArray = commingArray => {
  console.warn(commingArray);
  if (commingArray !== null && commingArray !== undefined) {
    const res = commingArray.map(arr => {
      return arr.map((innerArr, i) => {
        return [...innerArr, i, false]
      })
    })

    this.setState({
        commingArray: res
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Coming Array ==> ", commingArray);
      }
    );
  }
}
```